# Multiple java threads using native interface vs single java thread for multi threaded native

Tags: java, c++, c, java-native-interface

Im preparing for a project using JNI to accelerate some calculations for physical modeling. Native part does the calculations on a group of arrays each having more than 10M elements.

**Question:**  Which option would be more suitable for performance:

1) Using 8 threads in java each working on 1/8 part of arrays through a native call(jni-->c++). Do I need to crop whole array into smaller arrays to prevent unnecessary array copying?

2) Using single thread in java that calls a native which is 8-threaded (pthreads?)
Can I use pointer arithmetics to select only the necessary part to use in a thread?

I need to work on a single copy(or original) of arrays, does a c++ thread copy the whole array for itself? What about java thread? Which one isnt copying, I will use that one.

Note: Im using `GetPrimitiveArrayCritical()` to prevent array copying(working on original) of JNI interface.
Calculations take long enough that JNI overhead can be neglected.

`GetPrimitiveArrayCritical()` pins the java array so GC stops working until native function releases it, does this affect  other java threads accesibility?

**Actually all is in a `extern "C"` if it is important** .

OS: 64 bit windows7
CPU: fx8150
jvm: 64 bit
GCC: 64 bit

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From a design perspective, I would prefer approach #1 because it means that you don't have to manage threads in your JNI code. This adheres to the "single responsibility principle": your native code only needs to change if your algorithm changes. I also think that the facilities (threadpools and futures) that Java provides are easier to use than direct threads.

However, if you do this you should pay particular attention to the [warning](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/design.html#wp743) about pinning and unpinning arrays from multiple threads.

A better approach IMO is to allocate a *direct* `ByteBuffer`, and access it from JNI using [GetDirectBufferAddress](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html#get_direct_buffer_address). This would let you use a Java-side threadpool to manage the work, and would eliminate any native-side concerns about buffer copies.

Comment: Thanks, the gcc flags mentioned in warning is good. I will wait for some other answers too, otherwise I will except yours. You mean I should crop the array into 8 parts then feed them to separate threads that are using native functions. This way, they cannot unpin eachothers arrays with unfinished work.

Comment: @huseyintugrulbuyukisik - No, I think the best way is to keep a single buffer and pass the workers ranges of addresses in that buffer. Don't use primitive arrays at all.

Comment: I havent used any direct buffer in java. Can you give an example if you dont mind please? Actually used for jmonkey engine but that must be different right? I used FloatBuffer.

Comment: Does directbytebuffer get pinned/unpinned?

Comment: @huseyintugrulbuyukisik - a direct buffer lives on the C heap, so there's no need to pin/unpin (or more correctly, it's always pinned). Once you get its address (from the method I linked), you use it just like a C array.

Comment: And as for an example: trying to write one that's comprehensive will take more time than I can spare. I recommend Googling for bytebuffer examples, and trying some code. It's pretty easy.

Comment: Thank you verymuch. I will google more for that. This may be the savior because even GC cannot change its address and I can deliberately  try new buffers until I get a 32B- aligned one or can test from JNI if it needs to be shifted some bytes.

Comment: Do directbuffer get garbage collected after nothing has a reference of it ?

Comment: Or I just allocate for a size of 32Bytes more to select the proper offset inside of single buffer. Thanks. Problem is going to be solved.

Comment: @huseyintugrulbuyukisik - good solution. I believe that direct bytebuffers are page-aligned on Linux, although I recommend Googling for more info. They will get collected, although there's a JVM flag (can't remember the name) that's needed if your Java-side GC isn't running frequently enough to get rid of buffers.

Comment: After some trials, obviously, latest java makes it 32B aligned %90 of the tests, %10 of these are 16B aligned so I put a custom offset for that. Still trying to wrap the vector multiplication and nbody right now.